# Would like to get sum of payment in interval during 36 month from date of file creation - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, intervals

I have two tables.

- In first table "customers" I have 3 colums, first column is "id" (unique for every customer) and in second column is "date_created" (the date when the customer file was created). Dates are ranging in format 'yyyy-mm-dd' from 2007 till date. The third column is "client_name" (the name of client to which customer belongs)
- the second table is "payments" table with 3 colums, "id" (unique for every customer), in second column is "amount" of payment and in third column is "date_payment".

What I would like to achieve is next. From the first table I would like to choose files, created within a date range (for example from 2018-06-01 till 31.12.2018) and get sum of payment from second table after one month of creation, etc.. till month 36. Interval is attached for every particular claim, so it is different for every separate claim. The purpose of this is to get success rates from on month of creation, 2 month from creation, till month 36...

The result would be:

```
 interval client_name   sum   
 1        Boden         100
 2        Boden         220
etc... till 36
```

Close results i get with next query but it is very time consuming, so I would need some quicker solution that would return results for 36 month intervals for every each claim.

```
select customers.client_name, sum(payments.amount) as sum_amount
      from customers
      left join payments on customers.id=payments.id
      where customers.date_created >= '2018-06-01' and customersdate_created <= '2018-12-31' 
      and date_payment <= date(date_created + interval '1 month) 
      and client_name ilike '%Boden%'
      group by customers.client_name
```

Can anyone help, please?

UPDATE

Nobody answered but I kind of figure it out myself. Solution below:

```
select customers.client_name, sum(payments.amount) as sum_amount, 1 as sortorder
          from customers
          left join payments on customers.id=payments.id
          where customers.date_created >= '2018-06-01' and customersdate_created <= '2018-12-31' 
          and date_payment <= date(date_created + interval '1 month) 
          and client_name ilike '%Boden%'
          group by customers.client_name
UNION
select customers.client_name, sum(payments.amount) as sum_amount, 2 as sortorder
          from customers
          left join payments on customers.id=payments.id
          where customers.date_created >= '2018-06-01' and customersdate_created <= '2018-12-31' 
          and date_payment <= date(date_created + interval '2 month) 
          and client_name ilike '%Boden%'
          group by customers.client_name
```

Comment: A couple formatting tips. For Code after creating select it and click the {} icon (or ctl+K). For tabular data enter a line both above and below that contains only ```. This will also work with code.  You may want to see the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for additional tips.

Comment: You are requesting help on performance. Then please post actual table definitions (ddl script) including all indexes. Additional post the explain plan using [Explain  Analyze](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE). Finally post sample test data - as formatted text, **no images** - and the expected results of that data.

Comment: I actualy solved with parameters and union.

Comment: Cool. I do not know if you have the reputation but if you do post your then accept it. This provides a solution for future  questioners having similar issues and removes the question from the unanswered queue.